# Explain the output of the program

Tags: c, output

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int x=10,y=20;
    if(!(!x)&&x)
      printf("x=%d\n",x);
    else
      printf("y=%d\n",y);
     return 0;
}
```

the output is 10. how?
please show value of x in each step.

Comment: Your supposed output doesn't match the code.

Comment: "please show value of x in each step" -- Please read the FAQ. **You** should show the value of x at each step. If you get one wrong, we can point it out.

Comment: The `!` operator returns 0 unless its argument is 0, in which case it returns 1.  Therefore, `!!x` returns 0 if `x` is 0, and 1 otherwise.  The result of `1 && 10` is 1 or true, so the first `printf()` is executed.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Of course it does (if the question is properly parsed ... hopefully you're not talking about the '.').

Comment: @JimBalter: There is no place in the code that would output just "10".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yeah, hey, that's relevant ... not.

Comment: Anyway, too much time spent on this all around ... are people this desperate for low-hanging fruit that we get 6 equivalent answers to a question that shouldn't have been asked?

Answer (score 7):

First, operator precedence is as follows

```
() > ! > &&
```

Now, solving based on above precedence

```
 1. (!x)  = 0
 2. !(!x) = !(0) = 1
 3. (1 && 10) = 1// hence, true.
 4. hence, print x = 10
```

Comment: +1 one for mentioning precedence, which is crucial.

Comment: One from my side too.

Comment: @Jens Sure, but it would weird to expect the binary operator to bind more tightly than the unary operator, and even weirder for it to cross over the parens and bind more tightly than operators inside.

Answer (score 3):

`(!x)` is a boolean that checks whether x is zero, yielding zero if its operand is not zero, and one if its operand is zero. `if(!(!x))` is equivalent to `if(x)`, since it inverts `!x` which is the inverted value of x. This result is combined with the result of `x` by the `&&` operator. Since both the conditions are true, the if block is executed

Comment: (!(!x)) is equivalent to x ?????

Comment: What i mean is `if(!(!x))` is equivalent to `if(x)`

Comment: ok then please mention x is Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `!x` is `0` and then `!(!x)` is `1` which is true and the condition in `if()` i.e `(1 && 10)` becomes true so it prints `x=10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(!x) ==> (!10) ==> 0 
!(0) ==> 1
1 && 10 ==> 1
```

so you will get statement `printf("x=%d\n",x);` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Since x is 10,

`!x=0`

`!(!x)=1`

`1&&10` is true

hence print `x`,i.e `10`